# how do i recognize child view by dragging on parent view?

Tags: swiftui, drag

```swift
public var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text(text)
            ForEach(0..<row, id: \.self){ row in
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0..<col, id: \.self){ col in
                        GrassViewCell(
                            date: getDate(rowcol: [row, col], today: today),
                            color: blockColor,
                            inputLevel: getLevel(rowcol: [row, col])
                        ){ date in
                            text = date
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged{ gesture in
                    //how to recognize child view
                    //I just wanna childview's date by dragging cells
                }
                .onEnded{ _ in
                    text = formatter.string(from: today)
                    
                }
            
        )
        
    }
```

[image]

```swift
public struct GrassView: some View { //this is parent view
    @State private var text //where i want to put child's date
}
```

I just wanna know childview's date by dragging on parent and put that date in text

```swift
.gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged{ gesture in
                    //how to recognize child view
                    //I just wanna know childview's date by dragging cells
                }
                .onEnded{ _ in
                    text = formatter.string(from: today)
                    
                }
            
        )
```

is there any method that know childview by dragging??
i just tried attached .ontouchgesture() on childview but it didnt work
please help me..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDr6E.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a state variable in the parent view like so

`@State var text : String = "some text"`

and pass it into each child view as a binding

`GrassViewCell(textToDisplay: $text)`

and init at the top of `GrassViewCell` with `@Binding var text : String`. Then inside the gesture, just set `text = whatever_date_in_child` upon completion of the desired gesture.

Comment: i tried your solution but it worked once when i start dragging i just wanna know what gesture should be

Comment: The gesture should be tracking the end position of the child cell and if it's y coordinate is above some minimum, which is the bottom of the text frame.